# Create TableView Sections according to data in 3 Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have 3 arrays i.e todayAry, thisWeekAry, upcomingAry and I want to create sections according to data in all three arrays like if all arrays count is greater than 0 then 3 sections and if count 2 then two section and if no data in any of array then do not create that section then what is optimal condition to create it in tableView delegate method? Provide any alternative of this code!!
Thanks in Advance!!
Happy Coding!!

Currently my code is:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if self.todayDataAry.count > 0 {
        if self.thisWeekDataAry.count > 0 {
            if self.upcomingDataAry.count > 0 {
                return 3 // all sections today,this week,upcoming
            } else {
                return 2 //today,this week
            }
        } else {
            if self.upcomingDataAry.count > 0 {
                return 2 //today,upcoming
            } else {
                return 1 //today
            }
        }
    } else {
        if self.thisWeekDataAry.count > 0 {
            if self.upcomingDataAry.count > 0 {
                return 2 //this week, upcoming
            } else {
                return 1 //this week
            }
        } else {
            if self.upcomingDataAry.count > 0 {
                return 1 //upcoming
            } else {
                return 0 //no data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another array and store 3 arrays in it

```
var allDetails = [todayAry, thisWeekAry, upcomingAry]
var filteredDetails = allDetails.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

Then change like this. The filter removes empty arrays and returns non-empty arrays count.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return filteredDetails.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return filteredDetails[section].count
}
```

You can do the same in cellForRow method also

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
   var cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
   if cell == nil
   {
     cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "tripHistory")
   }
   cell.textLabel.text = filteredDetails[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I also want to know that which sections is created because I want to create rows according to count in each array i.e if todays sections is created then it's count is my number of rows but according to your solution how can i know about which sections is created?

Comment: again stuck in creating cell according to count!! can you please give me suggestions to create cell according to data ? because all sections have different cell and data according to it's count

Comment: In the `cellForRow` try something like... `if indexPath.section == 1 { let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) ...}` This would return the second array.

Comment: @Sachin Check updated answer. You can use this if all cells have same prototype cell.